# Creating bower projects that have dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, bower

I am creating a javascript client side library which I will make available via Bower and depends on two other libraries, one that is available via Bower (https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs) and another that is available only via npm (https://github.com/fent/randexp.js). I am concerned about how the users of my library would go about using it. My doubts and fears are:

- how can I declare the second library as a dependency of my library when it's only available via npm?
- after the user installs my library, will he/she have to be aware of the dependencies and manually include the corresponding javascript files in their index.html? I am aware of grunt-bower-install solving this issue, but I'm concerned about people who don't even use grunt at all.
- would it be so bad if I just gave up on all of this and included the code of said libraries in my own code?
- (bonus round): I want my library to be available as an AngularJS service, as a node.js module, and as a 'normal' javascript function. Is there a way for me to achieve this using only one repository or do I have to create 3 separate projects?

Comment: bower can resolve dependencies via git, you should look into that. in other words you can state a github project, either if it's not a bower project as a dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to wrap the second library in a bower package if you want it to be available to the bower package management system. `npm` is something entirely different and you won't be sharing between the two directly.

2) Yes, the user needs to ensure the dependencies are loaded in the right order on each page. Bower just ensures your dependencies are installed and at the correct version.

3) Generally, I'd avoid this. They're separate projects with orthogonal concerns. This is why we've created package managers like bower to begin with.

Bonus:

4) Yes, you can achieve this with one repository. Each package management service requires their own configuration files - but there's nothing wrong with having a `bower.json` and a `package.json` both sitting at the root of your repository. You just use `npm` and `bower` separately and respectively to publish to each system.

PS. This should have been more than 1 question.

Comment: I solved the randexp.js dependency problem by adding the url of the minified js file as a bower dependency in my bower.json. I will provide a bower.json for the angular module, a package.json for the node module, and a standalone js file for use in-browser.